# OpenTok audio and video controls are not appearing in react-native application

Tags: react-native, video-processing, react-native-ios, opentok

I am using OpenTok for video chat but default audio and video controls are not appearing, simple publisher and subscriber video appears with no options to turn off video or mute audio.

Meanwhile, Audio and video controls are appearing in react web application.

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
    <OTSession apiKey={this.apiKey} sessionId={this.sessionId} token={this.token}>
      <OTPublisher style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} />
      <OTSubscriber style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} />
    </OTSession>
  </View>
```

Can anyone please guide if I need to made any configuration changes so audio and video control can appear.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `<View />`

And you use `audioTrack` `publishAudio` `publishVideo` `videoTrack` option

```js
    <OTSession apiKey={this.apiKey} sessionId={this.sessionId} 
    token={this.token} audioTrack={true} publishAudio={true} publishVideo={true} videoTrack={true}>
      <OTPublisher style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} />
      <OTSubscriber style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} />
    </OTSession>
```

Comment: I tried but still default media controls are not appearing